# JavaScript closure not showing parameters properly

Tags: javascript, closures

I was playing a bit with closures in order to learn them, and made this code:

```
function showName(a,b,c){
  (function nombresAnidados(a){
  (function(b){
    (function(c){
      console.log("hola " + a + " " + b + " " + c);
    })(a)
  })(b)
})(c)
}

showName("cat","dog","horse");
```

I was expecting it to print out: "Hi, cat dog horse" but instead it prints: "Hi, horse dog horse"

Please, run it here:

```js
    function showName(a,b,c){
      (function nombresAnidados(a){
      (function(b){
        (function(c){
          console.log("Hi, " + a + " " + b + " " + c);
        })(a)
      })(b)
    })(c)
    }
    
    showName("cat","dog","horse");
```

What causes this behavior?

Comment: You passing parameters in reverse order in nombreseAnidados and the next 2 functions.

Comment: ... the calles should be `})(c) })(b) })(a)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try :

```js
function showName(a, b, c)
  {
  (function nombresAnidados(x)  // here your arg a get the value of c
    {
    (function (y)
      {
      (function (z)
        {
        console.log(  `hi : ${x} - ${y} - ${z}` );
        })(a) // --> z   (cat)
      })(b)  // --> y   (dog)
    })(c)   // --> x   (horse)
  }

showName("cat", "dog", "horse");
```

note: your code is not really a closure ;)

Answer (score 1):

The previous response will print "horse - dog - cat", but you wanted "cat - dog - horse".

What I think you want is this:

```js
function showName(a, b, c)
  {
  (function nombresAnidados(c)
    {
    (function (b)
      {
      (function (a)
        {
        console.log(  `hi : ${a} - ${b} - ${c}` );
        })(a) // a (cat)
      })(b)  // b (dog)
    })(c)   // c (horse)
  }

showName("cat", "dog", "horse");
```

Also, this is indeed a Closure as the inner functions in the chain has access to the outer functions variables. The most inner function, can access b and c variables from the outer functions, but you can't access both of those variables from outside that inner function scope.